# How can I display a UIImage on top of a CAShape Layer?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, uiimage, cashapelayer

I'm having trouble drawing a `UIImage` in front of a `CAShapeLayer`. I have a vector image in the background with an icon in front of it. The vector is important because I'm eventually scaling & animating this; and I have a ton of these onscreen so for performance I'd like to do this at a lower level than with a bunch of `UIImageView` subviews.

I've tried:

- Setting the container view's layer class to `CAShapeLayer`
- Adding a `CAShapeLayer` as a sublayer of my container view
- Setting my container's layer and/or sublayer's `content` to the image's `CGImage`
- Manually drawing the image in the container view's `drawRect` (my Quartz-fu is pretty weak, though)

In most cases I get the image drawn behind the shape (I vaguely understand that this is due to how `CAShapeLayers` composite themselves) or no image at all. Surely this is possible without resorting to subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the **zPosition** of a sublayer to a positive value? The default is 0.0, so making it larger than zero would push it "higher" in the hierarchy.

Comment: I've tried `insertSublayer:above` and `insertSublayer:below`, which I assume must do the same thing. I think I'm missing something more fundamental.

Comment: I don't think it does the same thing. As far as I remember, It only rearranges objects in sublayers array, it does not change their zPosition.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The docs say: `Inserts the layer into the receiver’s sublayers array, above the specified sublayer.` I took that to mean it would adjust the Z index, but that's not the case.

Comment: So did setting zPosition finally made it for you? Asking out of curiosity ;)

Comment: Yeah, I checked the `sublayers` array and in fact all of my layers had a Z index of 0. Now the question is, is there a better/smarter way that doesn't involve maintaining multiple sublayers when my root layer's content is nil...